# Does "within the same day" make sense?

Tags: expressions

Does the expression "within the same day" make sense? I want to say something like "if I go today, I can't come back within the same day," or "I if I get banned from a forum, I can't log in within the same day." Or, like, "I can't post the same thing twice within the day."

Comment: Yes, though the meaning of "day" can vary a lot: any 24-hour period; midnight to midnight; sunset to sunset; etc.

Comment: So, "within the same day" isn't wrong? This girl looked at me funny when I said "when I force-quit the Internet Explorer, I can't open it within the same day; I have to wait a day after shutting my computer off."

Comment: Uhmm, She didn't look at you funny because of *within the same day*.   What would happen if you shut your computer off and restarted it within the same day??

Comment: Oh, so maybe that's the reason? :) But I guess I kind of wanted to imply how retarded my computer was... And I couldn't find any searches on the expression "within the same day," so I was worried that I might have sounded stupid.

Comment: Sorry, no advice on how to talk to girls. You gotta figure that out for yourself.

Comment: You couldn't find any searches (search results) on the expression? 15,400,000 (minus this post) results in 1.68 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not technically wrong, it's confusing because "within the same day" can mean within the same calendar day or within the same 24 hours. It's typically better to say "If I've been banned from the forum, I can't post anything for 24 hours."

Answer (score 1):

It might be written in the sense of “within the given time”. But it is technically 
improper using “within the same day”. For example:

> I can complete the work within 4 hours.

But this sounds improper:

> I can complete this work within the same day.